# Azure SQL How to Check Partition Logic

Tags: database, azure, azure-sql-database

I have table where i have partitioned it by `day` , my table

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
    date DATE,
     /// other fields
   
) on dailyPartitionScheme(date)
```

When i do the query

```
Select * from test where date = {d '2023-05-30'}
```

Will it go the respective partition  or it will scan whole table ? How i can verify this which partition it  isscanning ?

I have three more filters which will present in all my queries i.e `dep_id` , `id` and `last_seen`

Should i create clustered index on these 3 fields to have optimal query performance ? Do i need to include `date` also in my index ?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is when you query example: `SELECT * FROM Day_table WHERE last_seen = {d '2023-05-30'}`
It will only scan the respective partition that corresponds to the **date '2023-05-30'** in the **"last_seen"** column.

If you want to verify which partition the query is scanning, you can use In **SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)**.
**SQL Server Profiler tool** to capture the queries executed against the database and determine which partition is being accessed.

For example I have created a Table called  Day_table. with the below Schema.

```
CREATE TABLE Day_table(
    dep_id INT,
    id INT,
    last_seen DATE,
    data VARCHAR(50),
    day_of_week VARCHAR(20)
);
```

Using the query Select last_seen from Day_table where `last_seen = {d '2023-05-30'} and Select * from Day_table where last_seen = {d '2023-05-30'}`

[image]
I want to see  which partition it is scanning.

In order to view this you can go to the sql Profiler
In **SSMS Tools Tab>SQL server>Connect to your SQl server with authenication>Events Selection>**
[image]

select the "**SQL:BatchCompleted**" and "**RPC:Completed**" events.

[image]

Click on the "**Column Filters**" button to set filters for the query.

In the "Column Filters" window, choose "**TextData**" from the "Column Name" drop-down list.

Set the filter operator to "**Like**" and enter the query you want to trace, for example:
[image]

```
Like '%SELECT * FROM Day_table WHERE last_seen = {d ''2023-05-30''}%'
```

[image]

And regarding the Clustered Index you can Use the 3 feilds for better performance.
I have applied the clustred index for the table

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IDX_Clust_Index_Day_table
ON Day_table (dep_id, id, last_seen);


SELECT *
FROM Day_table
ORDER BY dep_id, id, last_seen;
```

[image]

Comment: I am using Azure Data Studio there i can't find...

Comment: @Marcin_S In Azure data Studio as per my knowledge You can try with the SELECT is_query_store_on FROM sys.databases WHERE name = 'YourDatabaseName';
the above query. try this once and let me know if it helps

Comment: It giving me `1`  and also in above snapshot where it is mentioned the partition it's going ?

Comment: Could you please provide me more details about the error it would be helpful for further investigation.